# PO file not showing all the strings

Tags: woocommerce

I have a few strings (Woocommerce) which are shown in the Notepad++, but when I open the .po file in Poedit, they are not visible there (I also tried POEditor, and it's the same). And these translations cannot see on the website, but the links seems to be fine. The file is in UTF-8 without BOM. Have you got an suggestion?

Comment: You gonna get negative / downvote for your question. Please be very specific and provide the source which produce issue. Here the POT file. Tagging properly its not very related to woocommerce. There may be an issue in POT file and not with the woocommerce.

Comment: Those strings may not be passed through lang transer functions, check them, or may be your textdomain mismatching